How can I determine how much power is in a frequency range via FFT in LTspice?
When using LTspice, I can see the FFT of a voltage.  How can I see how much power is in a particular frequency band, and what portion of the total power it is?
The FFT in LTspice is in dB, but it's not clear what the dB are relative to.

If you ask it for the FFT of a node voltage, then it's dB voltage, not dB power.

The FFT scaling is in dBV RMS. You can right-click on the FFT scale and select linear, log, and dB scaling. Perhaps this discussion answers your question. You may want to do the calculations in a maths program.  LTspice allows you to export data to a text file (right-click in the middle of the graph).
